Identify what is causing GCC to add signal, abort, etc. to the linking process
I have a program I'm compiling that has strict memory limitations, and it seems a change was made that causes GCC to link to the stdlib files for abort, raise, signal, etc. This adds significantly to the bss size. Is there a way to identify the offending code that caused GCC to make this decision?
From what I understand, it's typically caused by not properly checking a pointer for NULL before using it.
Also, is there a way to disable this 'automatic' behavior?

Did you use any options like -fsanitize=XXX when compiling?

Isn't the code under source-control?
